# Does this durood contain shirk?

Tags: arabic-translation

The Qu'ran that I have contains a dua khatmul Qu'ran at the end. The ending durood however seems wrong to me but I don't know arabic well enough to be sure.
Can somebody kindly translate the durood at the end and clarify if it contains shirk or not.
Jazakallah khairan.[image: The Durood is at the end]

Comment: Why should it contain shirk?

Comment: It says something about noor e arsh, I think it probably doesnt contain it but I dont really understand arabic well enough to know and would like to know for sure.

Answer (score -2):

This is a bidah. Innovated thing. There is no such durood. There is only one durood which is the durood of Ibrahim which we say in tashahhud. Also please note that there is no such thing as khatmul Quran. Quran is there to read, understand and implement at all times. You should always buy Quran that has been certified by competent authority. How do you know the Quran that you are reading doesn't have a single mistake. For example, my Quran is certified by competent scholar. [image: Certification]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do realize that the durood isnt authentic but my two questions that remain are, what does the durood actually say? and 2) Would it be shirk to say that Prophet peace and blessings be upon him is made out of noor e arsh?, I would say that saying so is defintely wrong but isnt shirk but if you  can answer with evidence that would be great.

Comment: to @Mohd, why would you even want to say noor e arsh ? He is (peace be upon him) a human like us, a slave of Allah.

Comment: @muslimpro56 I dont want to, I clearly said that is "definitely wrong" if you read my comment you'd know but I want to specifically know if it is shirk or not.

Comment: @Mohd How can I bring evidence for something that doesn't exist? Your question is irrelevant because there is nothing called Noor e arsh. Yes you commit shirk if you believe Prophet Muhammed(ﷺ) is created out of Noor. You need to understand what is Noor on the very first place. There are two types of Noor. One physical light, second spiritual light(Knowledge and Guidance). Allah says Allah is the Noor of heavens and earth in Surah 24 verse 35. This means Allah is originator of both physical light and spiritual light.